# How to expand stroke beyond width of svg rect?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I'm using the npm package [`react-calendar-heatmap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar-heatmap) which generates a single svg containing `g`s and `rect`s for the weeks and days. I'm wanting to add a border in between the months of the svg to help provide some visual separation.

Using CSS I was able to add border to the first days of the month, but since the days are these individual `rect`s there is a small gap in between the days.

[Image of `react-calendar-heatmap` with stroke borders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqxxu.png)

Below are the classes being used to add the borders.

```
    .left {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-dasharray: 0,30, 10, 10;
    }

    .topLeft { 
        stroke: black;
        stroke-dasharray: 10,20,10,10;
    }
```

I'm not super familiar with svgs, and if it's even possible to do what I'm wanting. Is there a way to extend the strokes beyond the width/height of their respective `rect` to fill the gap between each square? Is it possible to do this without increasing the width of the stroke or moving the position of the `rect`? Appreciate the help.

Comment: sure just increase the stroke-width and/or set shape-rendering: crispEdges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a better idea to add a `<path>` element directly after each square that represents the first of a month. The `transformDayElement` prop gives you an opportunity:

```
transformDayElement: (element, value, index) => {
    const daysInWeek = 5;
    const squareSize = 10;
    const gutterSize = 1;

    return (
        <>
            { element }
            { value.date.getDate() == 1 && 
              <path className="monthDivide" d={`
                  M ${-gutterSize / 2},${daysInWeek * (squareSize + gutterSize) - gutterSize}
                  V ${element.props.y - gutterSize / 2} 
                  h ${squareSize + gutterSize} V 0`} /> }
        </>
    );
}
```

Ideally, you could get the values for the constants in that function from the parent component, but they are not part of the props passed to `element`. So you have to figure out the right values yourself from other code:

```
daysInWeek: DAYS_IN_WEEK in constants.js
squareSize: SQUARE_SIZE in index.js
gutterSize: props.gutterSize of the heatmap component
```

Finally, you need some CSS for the path:

```
.monthDivide {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so this is really close. I was using your solution and I have no idea how to adjust svg paths. So the calendar heatmap is still accounting for the two days that I'm removing, ie Saturday and Sunday. So there is a line addition at the top and needs to be moved to the bottom. How would I adjust the path that you provided to account for that? Everything that I'm doing is either making the path smaller or shifting it right or left. Appreciate the help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y1XE.png

Comment: I see. I'd think you could change the string interpolations in the `d` attribute like this: 1. exchange `daysInWeek` with  `(daysInWeek + 1)` 2. at the end, exchange the `0` with the interpolation `${squareSize + gutterSize}`.

Comment: The other thing I see is that some lines are missing, presumably because the first of the month is among the removed days. You seemed to have solved that when you set the `topLeft` class on the correct squares. You need to identify the same squares for my solutions.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was able to make some changes based on the edge cases and accommodations for the missing lines, but your solution really helped me out, thanks!